# Tell jQuery to execute certain code only once

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to tell jQuery to do something only once? E.g. right now, I need jQuery to on click of div, append some HTML. Then, every time someone clicks that div again it toggles hide/show. Is there a way to do this? I'm trying not to be too confusing.

EDIT: Solved!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`one`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one#typedatafn) method.

For example:

```
$('#myDiv').one('click', function() {
    $(this).append('...').click(function() { ... });
});
```

Comment: Instead of upvoting the comment, you could upvote the answer.

Comment: Maybe someone approves of the principle of explaining a downvote rather than approving the answer?

Comment: Even though, this ultimately did solve my problem, it was what I was looking for in the first place. This is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

Firstly you could use a marker and then remove it:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="not-initialized">
  ...
</div>
```

with:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("not-initialized")) {
    $(this).removeClass("not-initialized");
    // append content
  } else {
    $(this).toggle();
  }
});
```

Secondly, you could change event handlers:

```
$("#mydiv").click(append_content);

function append_content() {
  ...
  $("#mydiv").unbind("click", append_content).click(toggle_display);
}

function toggle_display() {
  $(this).toggle();
}
```

Or you could do things like testing the div to see if the content is there.

Comment: I tried testing whether the content existed, edited my post with the details...or should I start a new topic?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`one`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one) method. Alternatively you could use `hide` or `show` instead of `toggle`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's toggle: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle